# Segmentation Fault Linked List C++ Insert at End

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

My program is compiling but I'm getting a seg fault when I attempt to run this code. What I'm trying to do is append an element to the end of a linked list. Here is what my application is doing:

```
int main()
{
  linklist<int> l;
  int i = 30;
  l.insertEnd(i);
  return (0);
}
```

And here is the implementation of the function from my class:

```
template <class T>
void linklist<T>::insertEnd(T anItem)
{
  if(this->headPointer = NULL)
    {
      headPointer = new node(anItem, NULL);
    }
  else
    {
    node* endPointer = headPointer;
    while(endPointer->linkPointer != NULL)
    {
      endPointer = endPointer->linkPointer;
    }
    endPointer->linkPointer = new node(anItem, NULL);
    }
};
```

Lastly, here is how my node is set up:

```
class node
   {
   public:
     T dataItem;
     node* linkPointer;
     // construct a new node and initialize its attributes with the given parameters.
   node(T i, node* l): dataItem(i), linkPointer(l)
     {
     };
   };
   node* headPointer;    
};
```

Comment: Your equal sign should be a comparison operator.

Comment: And your question actually is please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like issue in this statement, here instead of comparing you are assigning.

```
if(this->headPointer = NULL)
```

Use this:

```
if(this->headPointer == NULL)
```

or

```
if(NULL == this->headPointer) // This is better way to compare.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class T>
void linklist<T>::insertEnd(T anItem)
{
    if(this->headPointer == NULL) //you were assigning null instead of comparing
    {
         headPointer = new node(anItem, NULL);
    }
    //rest of the code here
```

Try this

Comment: From next time do some analysis before posting the question

Comment: I appreciate the help, but i did spend over 4 hours snagged on this. I didn't know the '=' could even possibly be an issue. It was compiling, just not running.

Comment: Yes well, it's a computer after all. Perfection in coding is a necessity.

Comment: @RMK Switching on all compiler warnings and obeying thoroughly what they're telling you, might have been saving you a lot of time.